# Does WebRTC make sense for low-latency streaming over local network?

Tags: python, stream, webrtc, real-time, robotics

I am developing a python application where a drone and a computer communicate over local network (wifi). My need is to stream the drone's camera to OpenCV-python on the computer with the lowest possible latency at the highest possible resolution.

Thus far I have been trying rather naive approaches over TCP that give okay-ish results, I get something like 0.1s or 0.2s latency for VGA format. It has a point for some use cases as it enables lossless transmission, but since the most common scenario is to aggressively control the drone in real time from the stream, I am aiming for something of much lower latency and hopefully higher resolution.

My advisor has recommended using WebRTC. I have done some research on the matter, found the `aiortc` library that implements WebRTC in python, but I am unsure this is the way to go for my use case as it seems to be more geared toward web developers.

I am a bit lost I think. Could you highlight the advantages of WebRTC in my application if any, or point me toward solutions that are more relevant for my problem please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

[1][image: Protocol comparison]

rtc communicate peer to peer, I think you knew that. And if u use local network U will not need STUN server or TURN to connect two devices. That is make more decrease latency and code shorter. I'm not work with drone but I think your method stream had latency < 0,2 is good.
[fyi protocol campare](https://restream.io/blog/streaming-protocols/)